# Facebook wall post

Tags: android, facebook

Straight to the point.
I have an android app which makes status update and event post on facebook wall.
I am using the facebook sdk from this this web site https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidFacebookSample/tree/master/src/com/ecs/android/facebook/Sample

I am able to post events properly.
The problem is with posting status updates.
There is this menu option in my code , when I press Post On wall menu, a facebook dialoge pops up , which says Post to the wall and below is the text field where I am suppose to enter my status. But that field I want it to be pre-written with the text I am providing it with.

Please Help, Thanx in advance.
Please let me know if you need the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quoting** from **facebook** "Feed Dialog" docs:

> message
>   This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

---

In other words it seems that you can't prefill the post to wall dialog any more,
Instead you can do it by:
**Quoting** from **facebook** "User object" docs:

> issuing an HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/feed

---

for further info you can read:
-[FaceBook documentation for the **user** object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

-[FaceBook documentation for the **post** object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

P.S: If you aren't familiar with the FaceBook docs try to skim the android sdk that you are using to find some kind of method to post to the wall directly **without** using the Feed Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the graph's [post API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) (not to be confused with HTTP POST). I'm assuming you're using one of the [Facebook.dialog(...)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java) methods, just add to the `Bundle` parameter a key (`message`) and String value ("your message") pair to fill in the status.